# Can’t find the error, Go script doesn't work as expected

Tags: algorithm, go, debugging

I tried to solve this Leetcode problem  https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/
But it doesn't work for some reason, I really can't undestand what's wrong.
it just returns [-1 -1] whereas [100 137] is the right output.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    arr := []int{10, 40, 1, 4, 100, 137}
    targetVal := 237
    // twoSum(arr, targetVal)
    fmt.Println(twoSum(arr, targetVal))
}

func twoSum(nums []int, target int) []int {
    starter := 0
    // loop which is supposed to find first occurence of element that is less than target
    for i := 0; i < len(nums); i++ {
        if nums[i] < target {
            starter = i
            break
        }
    }
    // loop that iterates over remaining part of a slice (starting from nums[starter])
    for i := starter; i < len(nums); i++ {
        if target-nums[starter] == nums[i] {
            return []int{nums[starter], nums[i]}
        }
    }
    return []int{-1, -1}
}
```

I don’t have any debugging skills at the moment, so I just made sure that nums[starter], nums[i], all loops work as intended, I used fmt.Println() to log their values, and it seems to be in the right place, Idk what is wrong

Comment: The first element less than target is nums[0] here, with a value of 10. Why would you assume that there's another value in the array that is target-10?

Comment: You assume that the first element you find that's less than `target` is part of the solution, when that is not a valid assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it never goes inside the if

```
if target-nums[starter] == nums[i]
```

The **starter** variable will remain at 0 after passing through the first loop, as it will store only the first value smaller than the target.

If you're not worried about performance this O(n²) function can produce the right result:

```
func twoSum(nums []int, target int) []int {
    for i := 0; i < len(nums); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(nums); j++ {
            if nums[i]+nums[j] == target && i != j {
                return []int{j, i}
            }
        }
    }
    return []int{-1, -1}
}
```